# Returning an error - 'Variable does not exist' -

Tags: apex

I am returning an error that says: 'Variable does not exist: o.Id'.

I am unsure what the problem is.

Thanks,

```
public with sharing class closedWonNewBusinessRedirect{

    // property
    public Opportunity closedWonNBOpp {get; set;}

    // constructor for extension
    public closedWonNewBusinessRedirect(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        closedWonNBOpp = (Opportunity)controller.getRecord();                                  
    }

    public PageReference createOppAndRedirect(){
        try{

            // Field Mappings
            Opportunity o = new Opportunity();
            o.RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('New Business').getRecordTypeId();
            o.AccountId = closedWonNBOpp.AccountId;
            o.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId();
            o.CloseDate = closedWonNBOpp.CloseDate;
            o.Billing_Effective_Date__c = closedWonNBOpp.Billing_Effective_Date__c;
            o.Amount = closedWonNBOpp.Amount;
            o.StageName = closedWonNBOpp.StageName;
            o.Probability = closedWonNBOpp.Probability;
            o.Description = closedWonNBOpp.Description;

            // Values to populate the Opportunity name with: 
            String dateCreated = String.valueOf(Date.TODAY());
            String createdByName = UserInfo.getName();
            String accountName = [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Id =:closedWonNBOpp.accountId].Name;

            // Opportunity Name:
            o.Name = 'New Business created on ' + dateCreated + ' by ' + createdByName + ' for ' + accountName + '.';
            insert o;

             } catch (DmlException e){
            System.debug('The following exception has occurred from the closedWonNewBusinessRedirect.apxc: ' + e.getMessage());
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL, 'There has been an error with this page. Please email 123@gmail.com to log this issue.'));
             }

        // PageReferences        
        PageReference pageRedirectForClosedWonOpp = new PageReference('/apex/closedWonToContractPage');
        PageReference pageRedirectForNonClosedWonOpp = new PageReference('/'+o.Id); // THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS

        if(closedWonNBOpp.StageName == 'Closed Won'){
            pageRedirectForClosedWonOpp.setRedirect(true);
            return pageRedirectForClosedWonOpp; 
        } else { 
            pageRedirectForNonClosedWonOpp.setRedirect(true);
            return pageRedirectForNonClosedWonOpp;  
        }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have created an instance of opportunity inside your try block and you are accessing o.id outside the try block. The scope of the o variable is restricted only within the try block

Please move the opportunity instantiate line outside the try block.

```
 Opportunity o = new Opportunity();

 try{

            // Field Mappings

}
```

Comment: most welcome, happy I could help :) @AndyHitchings